# Encoding from xml to/from php?

Tags: php, xml, encode

So the xml has:
        `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>` 
and I'm supposed to load some of the nodes values and save to them. What encodings am I supposed to use? At the moment I'm using utf8_encode() which is kind of silly, but it works on save, but when I have to load the value again, it having scandic characters "ÅÄÖ", it shows like "Ã„Ã¤liÃ¶".

What can I use to encode the string to save and load to/from xml on php? The thing here is with the Scandinavian characters..

edit: sorry, i forgot to put the xml tag in {}...

edit: At the moment I'm using DOM Xpath to read and modify the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to use any encodings at all.

The internal encoding of XML documents is utf-8.
So, as long as you are using some designated parser, simplexml for example, it will recode document to utf-8 and you always have utf-8 output.

the rest depends on what you want to do with this data and what encoding your page in.

Comment: When I don't use utf_encode() on writing on the nodevalue and saving the xml, it swipes everything from the xml leaving only `<?xml version="1.0"?>` if the string that I want to save has chars as ÅÄÖ...

Comment: Please do one thing at a time. Do you have reading sorted out already? there are 2 ways of creating XML, direct one and by using whatever library. if you are using direct method, just like HTML, you can use whatever encoding - just set it up in the header. When using some library writer, you have to supply utf-8 encoded data, so, you may need to recode it.

Comment: `$xpath->nodeValue = utf8_encode($_POST['input'])` this works on writing, but on reading I've got only `echo $xpath->nodeValue` and if the element I want to read has Å, Ö or Ä it echoes something like "Ã„Ã¤liÃ¶"

Comment: what is your HTML page encoding? Do you have an idea of what encoding your site in?

Comment: I've got a form page which has no meta tags to define the encoding and the php page is just in `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: I am not talking of the meta tags. I am asking you about your site. Do you know at least what language your site in? What encoding  you are using in your editor to save files?

Comment: Is there a function to see it like phpinfo()?

Comment: it is not a function. it is your own native language. it is the encoding you are using to write your site. Don't you understand that? What encoding YOU ARE using?

Comment: My native language is Finnish if thats what you mean  :) just kidding...
what you're asking is probably ISO-8859-15?

Comment: You have two options: either have whole your site in UTF-8 (multi-language encoding that supports dozens on languages on one page) or recode every XML value you've got using `mb_convert_encoding($value,'ISO-8859-15','UTF-8');` (note the parameters order)

Comment: I'm gonna have to bump this a bit. So.. the server has ISO 8859-15 as its encoding and the XML file I need to modify has the same encoding. How do I make accented characters work on saving the modified xml file and reading it if it has these characters?

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) and [XMLWriter](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) classes, specifying the input and output encodings when you open the file. In your case, to read the document:

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader->open('test.xml', 'ISO-8859-15');
```

Values are then converted to UTF-8 automatically when you retrieve them from the document.

Remember that XMLWriter expects UTF-8 input.